# Calculate the norm of vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

Calculate the norm of vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1).$ We are on $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $\langle x,y\rangle=2x_1y_1+x_2y_2$. I know that I need to calculate the norm by $||x||=\sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}$, but I'm having difficulty using that.

Looking at the first one, some of my classmates are computing it as
$\sqrt{2\cdot 1\cdot1+0\cdot 0}$, but I don't understand where that comes from.

Personally, I was thinking it would be $\sqrt{2\cdot 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1}$, but honestly I'm not super confident there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The norm of $x=(1,0)$ is  $\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}=\sqrt{2x_1x_1+x_2x_2}=\sqrt{2\cdot1\cdot1+0\cdot0}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}||(1,0)|| & = \sqrt{\langle (1,0),(1,0)\rangle}\\ & = \sqrt{2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 0}\\ & = \sqrt{2}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}||(0,1)|| & = \sqrt{\langle(0,1),(0,1) \rangle}\\ & = \sqrt{2 \cdot 0 \cdot 0 + 1 \cdot 1} \\ & = \sqrt{1} \\ & = 1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The norm of $x=(1,0)$ is  $\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}=\sqrt{2x_1x_1+x_2x_2}=\sqrt{2\cdot1\cdot1+0\cdot0}$.  Now can you compute the norm of $(0,1)$?